# Number of integers that are sum of two squares

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I know that there's a proof (of Landau from 1908) that the numbers of integers that can be represented as sum of two squares which are smaller than $n$ is

$$
\Theta\left(n\over\sqrt{log (n)}\right)
$$

I would be thankful if someone can direct me to the proof (I only found a book in German),
or better yet if someone can prove it to me :)

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I may have found something in the right direction of what you are looking for [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-RamanujanConstant.html)

Which has a great amount of similarity to what you have asked, perhaps [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/phi_non_div_q.pdf) could be of some help as well, all of these links shows that:

$$
B(x) \sim \frac{Kx}{\sqrt{log(x)}}
$$
I hope this helps point you in the direction of a proof